# Error with environment variable expansion in ZSH

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

Run these commands:

```
[$] echo 'export VAR="qwertyuiop"
export VAR="$VAR:asdf=ghjkl"' > /tmp/vars.sh
[$] source /tmp/vars.sh
[$] echo $VAR
/home/saga/qwertyuiopsdf=ghjkl
```

As you can see, the variable substitution does not do what we expected. What is the issue here?

Comment: It does what some people expected.  [What were _you_ expecting?](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)

Answer (score 4):

The colon works as a modifier in `zsh`. Quoting [this reference](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers),

> After the optional word designator, you can add a sequence of one or
>   more of the following modifiers, each preceded by a ‘:’. These
>   modifiers also work on the result of filename generation and parameter
>   expansion, except where noted.
>
> **a**
>
> Turn a file name into an absolute path: **prepends the current directory, if necessary** (...)

All in all, the `:a` works as a modifier and prepends the current directory to `VAR` expanded value.

In order to prevent the modifier from acting, enclose the variable in curly braces: `VAR="${VAR}:asdf=ghjkl"`.

Comment: Note that those `$var:x` modifiers (though not that `a` one specifically which is a zsh extension) come from csh. bash supports them as well, but only for history expansion (like `!$:t`), not for parameter expansion (`$_:t`).

Comment: Note that if the `ksharrays` option is enabled, braces are required for those modifiers to be recognised (`$var:t` is then like `${var}:t`, you'll need `${var:t}`). Not that you'd want to enable that option, but that means the problem won't show up when zsh is running in `sh` or `ksh` emulation where that option is enabled.