# How do I write a function that has a double colon in a string without my current directory showing up in the string?

Tags: zsh, string, function

```
function awsl {
  echo "arg: $1"
  prfx='arn:aws:sts::'
  pstfx="$1:assumed-role/FOO/justin@bar.com"
  role="$prfx$pstfx"
  echo "role $role"
  saml2aws login --force --profile=default --role=$role
}

$ awsl 414204160037 

arg: 414204160037
awsl:4: no such file or directory: arn:aws:sts::$1:assumed-role/FOO/justin@bar.com=arn:aws:sts::/Users/justin.collum/work/stp-flow/v1/414204160037ssumed-role/FOO/justin@bar.com
role arn:aws:sts::$1:assumed-role/FOO/justin@bar.com
```

`/Users/justin.collum/work/stp-flow/v1/` is my current directory. I don't want it in that string. I thought splitting it up into two strings, one not interpolated, would do it. Tried escaping the :: with :: but that didn't work either.

Zshell on OSX.

Comment: See this recent answer: [Error with environment variable expansion in ZSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570483/65304)

Comment: Typo: `$role="$prfx$pstfx"` should be `role="$prfx$pstfx"`

Comment: That helped @steeldriver, want to write it up as an answer?